# Misunderstanding in sequential and combinational implementation, based on blocking or non-blocking behaviour

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, simulation, system-verilog, sequential-logic

I have a very simple module that waits for the `valid` signal to become `1` and then sets the `data` signal to `1` as below:

```vhdl
module test2(
    input clk,
    input valid,
    output reg data = 0
    );
    
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        if(valid) begin
            data <= 1;
        end
    end
      
endmodule
```

The problem is with my testbench. When I use the following testbench, the result is weird:

```
module test( );
    reg clk = 1;
    reg valid = 0;
    wire data;
    
    always 
        clk = #5 ~clk;
        
    initial begin
        @(posedge clk);
        @(posedge clk);
        @(posedge clk);
        valid =  1;
    end

    test2 uut(
        .clk(clk),
        .valid(valid),
        .data(data)
    );
    
endmodule
```

This leads to the following result:

[image]

As is obvious, the `data` signal and `valid` signal have changed their value at the same time (same `posedge clk`). Since we declared our design module sequentially, it should make a flipflop, but the result is not as flipflop behavior.

Furthermore, if I change the line `valid = 1;` to `valid <= 1;` in my testbench, the output is modified:

[image]

What is the problem here, and why does blocking or nonblocking assignment in the `initial` block in the testbench affect the design behavior?

I am using Vivado2023 for simulation.

Comment: Why did you un-accept the answer?  It completely answers your question.  [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

With the **blocking** assignment in the testbench (`=`), you have a simulation race condition.

The proper way to drive *synchrounous* inputs from the testbench in Verilog is to use **nonblocking** assignments (`<=`).  You should drive `valid` from the testbench in the same way you drive `data` from the design, namely using:

- The same edge of the clock: `@(posedge clk)`
- Nonblocking assignments

Using the nonblocking assignment in the testbench guarantees correct simulation behavior because it eliminates the simulation race condition.

It doesn't matter whether you are driving signals from an `initial` block or an `always` block.  Both types of blocks are used for **procedural** assignments.  You need to be consistent.